# MIPS Disassembly on a x86 machine using GDB; possible?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, x86, mips

I have a x86 development machine and developing kernel module for mips. I wanted to disassemble a routine to find problems with the module.

So my question is
"Can I disassemble it on x86 machine or I will have to get a MIPS development machine ?"

I tried it, but it disassembles in x86 instruction set.

Comment: If you are using a pre-built toolchain, it probably already includes a cross-compiled version of gdb.  If not, you can build your own as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically need some form of [cross compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). A cross compiler would allow you to compile on a host machine (x86 in your case) for a target machine (MIPS in your case). So you would be able to generate MIPS binaries from your x86 machine. Moreover, you would also get all the other tools associated to the compiler, such as `objdump`. Here you have a guide on [how to build a cross compiler for GCC](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

Assuming you are using `objdump` to disassemble a binary, you may not need to build a cross compiler. `objdump` belongs to [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and it may be possible to just compile binutils for using MIPS as the target (I have never tried to create a cross-platform build of binutils, so I am not 100% sure).

**EDIT:** I just read the title again, and realized that you are using `gdb`. In that case I believe you would need to create a full cross compiler, and create a cross-platform version of `gdb`.

Comment: http://opencores.org/project,mpx the mpx core is a mips clone, browse the repo trunk/gcc/build_gcc_linux.zip has a build script.  The patches simply remove the instructions not supported by mpx, you wont need to apply them.  it builds a gdb as well as the other tools with which you can disassemble to your hearts content.  dont need gdb to disassemble just binutils BTW.

Comment: But in case of cross-compilation I will have to execute the utilities on a MIPS machine. As far as I understand, cross-compilation is "compiling code on arch 1 to run on arch 2" not "compiling code on arch 1 to run on arch 1 and work for arch 2"

Comment: The OBJDUMP solution works. It now clearly shows mips instruction set and registers. Thank you !! You guys are awesome.